# How to retrieve simple xml from public Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working in an Arduino device in which I need to retrieve public data from a Google spreadsheet.

So far I have published the spreadsheet and I can access it at https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1uphj-Oq3Xt6ImHJdezAUEX4u41_w1NNMlZU4Flr6lc4/1/public/full?range=a11:c12 which can be opened in the browser or in the Arduino (I am working with a SIM800 module so it can work with HTTPS without problems).

The output of this is xml items like (I am not very into XML):

```
<entry>
<id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1uphj-Oq3Xt6ImHJdezAUEX4u41_w1NNMlZU4Flr6lc4/1/public/full/R12C11</id>
<updated>2018-04-30T05:31:51.590Z</updated>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006' term='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell'/>
<title type='text'>K12</title>
<content type='text'>12345</content>
<link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1uphj-Oq3Xt6ImHJdezAUEX4u41_w1NNMlZU4Flr6lc4/1/public/full/R12C11'/>
<gs:cell row='12' col='11' inputValue='12345' numericValue='12345.0'>12345</gs:cell>
```

One of them for every cell requested.
The thing is that here I can see too much unneeded/redundant information, for example, in "title" and "content" I get the same information as in "gs:cell", "updated" may actually be useful but "link" and "category" are completely disposable to me.

Since I will be working with an Arduino and a sim800 module (which cannot handle high data transfer speeds) making this as simple as possible will be great.

Probably there is a way to request this simplified in the HTTP call, maybe adding some parameters or changing "full" to something else.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retrieve the simpler response from `range=a11:c12` of the spreadsheet ID `1uphj-Oq3Xt6ImHJdezAUEX4u41_w1NNMlZU4Flr6lc4`. If my understanding is correct, how about retrieving values using Query Language? I think that there may be several methods. So please think of this as one of them.

### Pattern 1: Retrieve response as HTML

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uphj-Oq3Xt6ImHJdezAUEX4u41_w1NNMlZU4Flr6lc4/gviz/tq?range=a11:c12&tqx=out:html
```

#### Result :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>A11:C12</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr style="font-weight: bold; background-color: #aaa;">
<td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #f0f0f0">
<td>DataInCellA11</td><td>DataInCellB11</td><td>DataInCellC11</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #ffffff">
<td>DataInCellA12</td><td>DataInCellB12</td><td>DataInCellC12</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

### Pattern 2: Retrieve response as CSV

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uphj-Oq3Xt6ImHJdezAUEX4u41_w1NNMlZU4Flr6lc4/gviz/tq?range=a11:c12&tqx=out:csv
```

#### Result :

```
"DataInCellA11","DataInCellB11","DataInCellC11"
"DataInCellA12","DataInCellB12","DataInCellC12"
```

### Note :

- In this case, the response cannot be retrieved as the xml format. There is no `tqx=out:xml`.
- As a sample, you can retrieve values using curl and browser from above URLs.
- If you want to retrieve values from other sheets, please use the query of `gid`. In this sample, `gid=od6` which means 1st sheet is omitted.

### Reference :

- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, the "Pattern 2" was the best option for my situation, I still have to test it in the arduino, but as I checked I am sure it will work and output a simple csv which is exactly what I need

Comment: @Rodrigo Miranda I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.